# Is it possible for Deno and a web client to share TypeScript modules?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, deno

Deno tries hard to be compatible with the browser.  But every time I try to share code between Deno and the browser I run into trouble.  Is is possible to write TypeScript modules that can be imported by Deno code and by browser code?  If so can you point me to a sample program on the web?  Thanks.

I've tried this several times.  There are two issues I can't get around.

- Deno requires you to include ".ts" when importing modules, but normal TypeScript forbids it.
- I can't make VS Code edit all of these TypeScript files in the same workspace!  It blows up.

Here's my best attempt at this.  It's a template for a VS Code workspace.  It allows you to write shared code, but with a lot of limitations and other issues.  https://github.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/deno-client-server-typescript-template  This will show you what I'm trying to do and how far I've gotten.

I've done a lot of research, and I've seen a lot of bits and pieces of solutions.  But I'd love to see a complete sample program on github.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems to address here:

1. Deno requires imports with extension. Base TypeScript depends on whatever resolution system your runtime uses. NodeJS based TypeScript has to use CommonJS which forbids extension imports, while Deno based TypeScript uses official JavaScript modules, which require extension. Simplest solution for this is to choose a runtime and stick to it, this will save you a ton of headaches down the road, based on the simple fact that Deno and Node work very differently. Your VSCode extension and workflow should also change depending on whatever you choose. Though there are options like Denoify https://github.com/garronej/denoify which allow you to transform Node code into Deno code, which might be worth considering.
2. Sharing code between Deno and the browser. Not gonna happen the way you think it might. TypeScript isn't an actual executable programming language, but rather an abstraction over JavaScript that adds some nice things. That means in order to run your TypeScript code you need to transform it first into JavaScript, and there are quite a lot of tools to do so, like Bundler https://github.com/timreichen/Bundler or Denopack https://github.com/denofn/denopack . Just remember that tools like TSC are ment to be used only for Node TypeScript code, so they won't work with your Deno TypeScript code.

However if you want to skip this step you can always just write JavaScript code with JSCode annotations and modules, both Deno and the browser will run the code the same way, as long as you don't use the Deno namespace.

Comment: "to run your TypeScript code you need to transform it first into JavaScript"  Yes, I run the normal tsc command.  It's bound to my default build, control-shift-b

Comment: "transform Node code into Deno code" I am not trying to work with Node and Deno.  I'm trying to work with the browser and Deno.  I've tried several options in tsconfig to configure the module system.  "ESNext" came close but it didn't get around the file extension issue.

Comment: @Trade-IdeasPhilip What do you mean? Browser requires extensioned imports just like Deno.

Also, the problem you are experiencing is a runtime problem (code won't run) or is it that VSCode is giving you warnings?

Comment: "Browser requires extensioned imports just like Deno" If I was using JavaScript instead of TypeScript, I could use the same exact import statement.  But using deno + typescript I need to say import {...} from "./myfile.ts".  If I try to compile that in tsc I will get an error.  If I remove ".ts" the tsc is happy but Deno gives me an error.   Depending how I set up my project, Intellesense will enforce one of those rules or the other.

Comment: "a runtime problem (code won't run) or is it that VSCode is giving you warnings?"  I got the sample code to run.  But only by commenting out the things that would not compile.

Comment: @Trade-IdeasPhilip I see now what the problem is. You don't use TSC to compile TypeScript in Deno. Both implementations of TypeScript (Node and Deno) are very different as I said in my answer, that is why I recommended you those alternatives (Bundler and Denopack).

Comment: "Both implementations of TypeScript are very different "  I had some luck with the TypeScript API build into Deno.  But it was still a bit clunky and "unstable."  https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/5253#issuecomment-728469162  That's why I tried the standard tsc in this attempt.

Comment: "I recommended you those alternatives (Bundler and Denopack)."  I was hoping for a solution that didn't require any bundlers or packagers.  I'm willing to try, but I repeat my original question.  Can someone point me to a simple project that uses these two tools to share TypeScript library files between the client and server?

Answer (score 0):

To share TS modules between Deno and Web Browser you can use a custom web-server that switches TS requests to the JS files which Deno automatically generates.  For example...

```
// File DenoWebServer.ts
const port = 8082;
const server = Deno.listen({port});
console.log("Deno development server running on http://localhost:" + port + "/");

for await (const conn of server) {
    handleHttp(conn).catch(console.error);
}

async function handleHttp(conn: Deno.Conn) {
    const httpConn = Deno.serveHttp(conn);
    for await (const requestEvent of httpConn) {
        const url = new URL(requestEvent.request.url);
        const pathname = decodeURIComponent(url.pathname);


        try {
            let path = "." + pathname;
            if (pathname.endsWith(".ts")) {
                // Substitute TS with JS file that Deno generated.
                let cwd = Deno.cwd();
                const denoGen = "/Users/adam/Library/Caches/deno/gen/file"; // Change this!
                path = denoGen + cwd + pathname + ".js";
            }
            console.log(path);

            // Set content-type of actual file to keep browser happy
            let headers = {
                "Content-Type": mimeFromFilePath(path),
            };

            // Read file synchronously for simplicity.  Change to streaming for big files!
            let arB = Deno.readFileSync(path);
            const response = new Response(arB, {headers});
            await requestEvent.respondWith(response);
        } catch {
            const fail = new Response("400 Failed", {status: 400});
            await requestEvent.respondWith(fail);
        }
    }
}

function mimeFromFilePath(filePath: string): string {
    if (filePath.endsWith(".html"))
        return "text/html";
    else if (filePath.endsWith(".js"))
        return "application/javascript";
    else if (filePath.endsWith(".ts"))
        return "application/typescript";
    else if (filePath.endsWith(".js.map"))
        return "application/json";
    return "application/octet-stream";
}
```

Notes:

1. Please change "denoGen" to point to your Deno generation folder
2. It's critical to set the MIME type of JS files so the Browser loads them correctly.
3. When launching the server, remember to give it file read access to the generation folder as well as the current directory.  You can do this with "run --allow-net --allow-read=/ DenoWebServer.ts".  Or you should be more selective if your computer has sensitive data.
4. I'm using WebStorm as my IDE.  To get debug breakpoints to work I found I had to set the web root to the parent folder of my WebStorm project.
5. After editing your TS source you need to get Deno to generate JS files.  Currently I do this by making a little TS program that imports all my TS modules.  Then I run the little TS program to get Deno to rebuild everything.  I expect there is a better way but I have only been using Deno for 8 hours so far...
6. This method is OK for developing.  But for releasing your code I suggest you try to bundle your browser JS so it can work with any web server.